# Passagem de Parametros entre um jsp e dois servlts?

Tags: java-ee

Tenho uma duvida talvez um pouco difícil de ser esclarecida!!!

Estou a utilizar uma metodologia de programação chamada MVC, como  toda a gente conhece, e que nesta situação (Java EE) no controller fica os handler (servlts) no model ficam as classes e a view que neste caso e os JSP´s.

E a minha duvida é o seguinte:
Possou um form num jps em que, o que quero que aconteça quando carregar em submit, é fazer o seguinte:

1. Passar os parâmetros do formulário para um servelt que utilizo para criar um objeto.
2. Passar estes mesmo parâmetros para um outro servlet para ser mostrado num jsp a parte.

Sei porem que existe uma forma de passar estes parâmetros tal como utilizar uma variável de sessão, porem como sabem, não é muito aconselhável utiliza-la.

Comment: Sugiro utilizar então o jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa de dois servlets, seu problema é mais fácil de resolver do que isso:

1. Envie os valores do seu formulário para a servlet
2. Crie o respectivo objeto na servlet, persista ele, faça a mágica acontecer
3. Coloque o seu objeto no request, por exemplo `request.setAttribute("produto", produto);`
4. Redirecione para a sua jsp:

   `RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/produto.jsp");
   rd.forward(request,response);`

Agora você tem acesso ao objeto `produto` que está no request para expor a informação que você precisa.